# Run on android with react-native-web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I'm new to React and React Native, I want to build a cross platform app which would use native components on mobile platforms.

I installed and initialized a react-native-app and install react-native-web and I wonder how to start my boilerplate code on android emulator, the documentation doesn't tell how.

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands to get Demo Code

1. npm install -g create-react-native-app
2. create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
3. cd AwesomeProject
4. npm start or react-native start

Once you Get familiar to basics. I recommend you boilerplate code you must check out .
1. https://github.com/cubixlabs/ReactCube
2. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase
3. https://github.com/shoutem/ui

Comment: So should I first create a RN app then adding RN-web for browser support?

Comment: I believe RN apps can be run for Android and IOS , for Web App you Will have to See React JS. https://reactjs.org

Comment: They can, but there is a library : https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web that can bind one code for the 3 platforms. Just wonder how to really use it and just launch an Android emulator from it.

Comment: I think I have given your Answer check out my Second Answer . @MaximeB

Answer (score 0):

Web View Component index.js

```js
// @flow
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  WebView as WebViewRn
} from "react-native";

export default class WebView extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    source: PropTypes.object
  };
  static defaultProps = {
    source: {
      html: `
    <html>
     <header>
      <style>
       html, body {
        height: 100%;
       }
       html {
        display: table;
        margin: auto;
       }
       body {
         text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
       }
      </style>
     </header>
     <body>
      <p>No valid HTML provided</p>
      <p>source props is missing</p>
     </body>
    </html>
   `
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      source,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    return <WebViewRn source = {
      source
    } { ...rest
    }
    />;
  }
}
```

Component : Styles.js

```js
// @flow
import {
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Colors
} from '../../theme';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary.backgroundColor
  }
});
```

Container Class index.js

```js
// @flow

/*
Disable selection style
style="-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;"

Word wrap and break word style
style="word-wrap: break-word;"
*/
import {
  connect
} from "react-redux";
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  WebView
} from "../../components";

class Terms extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source = {
      {
        html
      }
    }
    />;
  }
}

const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <style>
  .container {
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  h2 {
   color: #000;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.2;
   margin-top: 25px;
  }

  p {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   text-align: left;
   line-height: 26px;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-style: normal;
   color: #000;
   font-size: 18px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container" style="-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;">
  <h2>Disclaimer</h2>

  <p>Always make sure to double check recipe and component ingredients (and where they are produced) if you have any health
   related issues to avoid particular foods. Please make sure to consult a doctor and always double check labels. Please
   notify us of any errors on the recipes itself. We strive to make information as acurate as possible for convenience, however
   we disclaim any warranty on it.</p>
  <p>Always consult a licensed physician or licesned nutritionalist for all medical, dietary and allergen issues. All information
   on our site “as is” has no warranty on it of any kind. Either expressed or implied. </p>
  <p>Rich thomas LLC and its partners disclaim all warranties expressed or implied including without limitation those of merchanitbility
   or fitness for a particular purpose and non fringement or arsiing from a course of dealing, usage, or trade practice.
   Rich Thomas LLC shall not be liable for any indirect, special, consequential, or incidental damages arising from any information
   present.</p>
 </div>
</body>

</html>`;

const mapStateToProps = () => ({});

const actions = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Terms);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm however just asking how to run my code on emulator or device.

Comment: Demo Code Can Run Emulator . I have make Component for Web View as Mention . You just have to Call that in Container and you will be able to see Web View  Response